# stored procedure error message

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have implemented the stored procedure as below, however i am getting the following error message when i try applying it:

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE symbol_id = id GROUP BY symbol_id;**

I did some debugging and found that it was caused by the @max variable which i am trying to write the result into, however i do not see anything wrong with the syntax, can anyone please advise?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GENERATE_REPORT`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `GENERATE_REPORT`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE id INT;
    DECLARE max INT;
    DECLARE at_end BIT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR
        FOR SELECT symbol_id from trade;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
        FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET at_end=1;

    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur INTO id;
    WHILE (NOT at_end) DO
        SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM trade INTO **@max** WHERE symbol_id = id GROUP BY symbol_id;
        FETCH cur into id;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cur;
END
```

$$
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax in your [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html):

Change

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM trade 
INTO @max -- Incorrect placement
WHERE symbol_id = id
GROUP BY symbol_id;
```

To

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
INTO @max -- Correct placement
FROM trade  
WHERE symbol_id = id
GROUP BY symbol_id;
```

The `INTO` should come right after the `SELECT` and before the `FROM`

Comment: ahhh! I had been looking at it for 2 hours and could not see that! thanks :)